# ReactJS toLowerCase is not a function

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, reactjs-native

I am doing a comparison by converting my text to lowercase and comparing its index to -1, in order to have some value to the particular field in `ReactJS`, but I am getting this error in JavaScript console:

> Uncaught TypeError: props.filterText.toLowerCase is not a function

```
var props = this.props;
var rows = this.props.episodes
    .filter(function(episode){
        return episode.title.toLowerCase().indexOf(props.filterText.toLowerCase()) > -1;
    })
    .map(function(episode){
       return <EpisodeRow key={episode.title} episode={episode}/>
    });
```

Comment: What value does props.filterText have?

Comment: Is `episode.title` a String? try episode.title.toString().toLowerCase() or console.log its' value to the console.

Comment: This is a pretty straightforward error - `props.filterText` is not a string. Just do a `console.log` inside your filter loop of `props.filterText` and you'll see it's not a string. My guess is that it will be `undefined`

Comment: @adam: would undefined cause a RefError "undefined has no property toLowerCase"... ?

Comment: Probably a very minor performance issue as well - but why do `.toLowerCase()` in a loop every time if you don't have to? `var filter = props.filterText.toLowerCase()` outside your filter function and do `indexOf(filter)` inside your function.

Comment: @dandavis - you're right, it's not `undefined` it's just something that's not a string. Could be a function, number, boolean, but not a string.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Looks like Chris's comment is the correct answer:

If *title* is a string, use **toString()** before toLowerCase():

```
return episode.title.toString().toLowerCase().indexOf(props.filterText.toString().toLowerCase()) > -1;
```

Comment: In my particular case, this solution rendered the text as "[Object] [Object]".  You shouldn't be guessing when coding in a strongly-typed language.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the problem :)

props.filterText is undefined.
=> The filterText:"" must be declared in the state before putting in props

Comment: I had this problem again 2 times.

Answer (score -1):

I think Adam's answer from the comments is actually correct, and turned out to solve my problem :

```
.filter(function(episode){
    if(episode.title) {
        return episode.title.toLowerCase().indexOf(props.filterText.toLowerCase()) > -1;
    } else {
        return '';
    }
})
```